# How to delete specific columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 2000 columns. Majority of the columns have "X111, X222 ,X123" and I want remove columns that starts with the name X

Comment: `df[grep("^X", names(df), invert = TRUE)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[,-grep("^X",names(df)]
```

Grep logic looks for words starting (`^`) with `X`.